# Cannot Download google-chrome-stable on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, apple-m1

I am getting an error when I try to run `docker build` the following Dockerfile on an M1 Mac.

My full Docker file is:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15

#Chrome
ARG CHROME_VERSION=98.0.4758.102-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

## ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=98.0.4758.102
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''
EXPOSE 4444

EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m","/app.jar"]
```

The error I get is regarding `google-chrome-stable`, specifically `package google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture`. The full error is:

```
docker build -t monolith-repo .
[+] Building 12.0s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15                                                                                                                                          0.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 122B                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15@sha256:aac64d9d716f5fa3926e6c8f43c680fa8404faae0b8a014c0c9b3d73d2d0f66a                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [3/5] RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1  && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome                                       11.6s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [3/5] RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1   && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome:                                                  
#7 0.232 Downloading metadata...                                                                                                                                                                                        
#7 5.286 Downloading metadata...
#7 9.705 Downloading metadata...
#7 11.53 error: Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:
#7 11.53  Problem: conflicting requests
#7 11.53   - package google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
#7 11.53   - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome]: exit code: 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I have to download a different version of google-chrome-stable? Or do I need to use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few key issues occurring:

Per https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable is (currently) only for linux/amd (*not* arm) architecture. When it says `package google-chrome-stable-98.0.4758.102-1.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture`, note the `x86_64`indicates it is linux `amd` (*not* `arm`). So The issue is that there is no image for it to pull.